# Django and React - Models for adding multiple data fields - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, material-ui

I am using Django for my backend and react for my frontend to build a web application that calculates cost based on the total volume (calculated using dimensions l*w*h) of some boxes. In order to do that, I created a form using React and Material UI in which there is an ADD MORE button to add the dimensions of multiple additional boxes. Below image showing part of the form.

Although I managed to create a model in case there is only one box and store the values in the database, I don't know how this will work when I use the ADD MORE button. How can I create my Django model to store the dimensions and volume for each additional box of the form?

I checked several other threads and found out about Formsets but I don't know how to apply it in my case.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Please share your code - frontend and backend - related to the question.

Comment: My react code was based on the code of this project https://github.com/candraKriswinarto/dymanic-form .  So if you can explain how to use Django as a backend of this project that would be appreciated as my code now is still not very clear